# Javascript array.push replacing previously added elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, foreach, botframework

I'm filling in an array with objects. Each time the for loop iterates, it's updating the previous items of the array.

I've tried with various types of loops like for-each, for and for of.

```
var arrResult = new Array;

for (let element of accessoriesToDisplay) {
    var obj = {};
    var obj = await AdaptiveCardImporter.accessoryCard(element.Name,
     element.Price, element.ProductDescription, element.URL, element.ImgURL);
    arrResult.push(obj);
}
```

This array should have 3 different objects at the end and not the array filled in with just the last one.
This code was working before I moved the accessoryCard method outside the main js file.

Watcher:

[image: Loop-1]

[image: Loop-2]

[image: Loop-3]

Comment: Can you please show more of your code. Where did you declare arrResult?

Comment: where is the rest of your code? what you wrote suggests that either accessoriesToDisplay has only one element or that the `await AdaptiveCardImporter.accesoryCard` does not resolve for 2 of them, are you sure this is not an issue with asynchornous nature of js and you logging/using data before it is written into the arrResult?

Comment: var arrResult = new Array; is declared outside the for loop. I'll update the OP. @JanneckLange

Comment: If you put a `console.log("Foo")` inside the loop, how many "Foo"'s do you see?

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski the obj gets updated every time the loop is executed with new obj every time. the problem is while performing .push operation on the array.

Comment: @KunalKene I *guarantee you* `push` is not replacing any objects!

Comment: Can't you use a `.then()` here? Or do you not have access to accessoryCard()'s code?

Comment: @Jamiec the loop is executed 3 times. The number of objects returned is 3.

Comment: Are you sure 3 objects are returned?

Comment: SOmething else is happening elsewhere. I promise you. Show us a [mcve] and you'll see the problem goes away.

Comment: yes, @Kobe I've debugged the code, at the arrResult.push(obj) I can see the array adding a new object to an array and replacing the array. I've used breakpoints everywhere to check the flow.

Comment: This code was working before I moved the accessoryCard method outside the main js file.

Comment: can you `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))` on each iteration?

Comment: after pushing the obj variable, at the end of for loop, add this code console.log(JSON.stringify(arrResult.length)); and check the console. most probably you will see a single log, instead of 3.

Comment: I've added watcher's to the OP. 1st, 2nd & 3rd loop.

Answer (score 0):

You code concept is fine. You code should execute normally, but you problem lies with your await - something there isn't right. For example this recreation of your code works:

```js
const getObj = e => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve({val:e}), 300))

async function main() {
  var arrResult = []
  var accessoriesToDisplay = [1, 2, 3]


  for (let element of accessoriesToDisplay) {
    var obj = await getObj(element)
    console.log(obj)
    arrResult.push(obj);
  }
  
  console.log(arrResult)
}

main()
```

But your code does not. Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))` on each loop iteration to check if the object returned is actually the object you are looking for - chrome likes to help out by automatically updating the value.

Comment: Agreed. In the watcher screenshot above you can see the contents of the obj as well. I'm guessing it's something to do with await as well. Not sure what.